# How to normalize unix timestamps to sum to discrete numeric values?

Tags: python, time-series, timestamp, unix-timestamp

I have an "ideal" formula in which I have a sum of values like

```
score[i] = SUM(properties[i]) * frequency[i] + recency[i]
```

with `properties` being a vector of values, `frequency`  and `recency` scalar values, taken from a given dataset of N items. While all variables here is numeric and with discrete integer values, the `recency` value is a UNIX timestamp in a given time range (like 1 month since now, or 1 week since now, etc. on daily basis).

In the dataset, each item `i` has a date value expressed as `recency[i]`, and a frequency value `frequency[i]`, and the list `properties[i]`. All properties of `item[i]` are therefore evaluated on each day expressed as `recency[i]` in the proposed time range.

According to this formula the recency contribution to the `score` value for the `item[i]` is a negative contribution: the older is the timestamp the better is the score (hence the `+` sign in that formula).

My idea was to use a re-scaler approach in the given range like

```
scaler = MinMaxScaler(feature_range=(min(recencyVec), max(recencyVec)))
scaler = scaler.fit(values)
normalized = scaler.transform(values)
```

where `recencyVec` collects all `recency` vectors for each data point, where `min(recencyVec)` is the first day and `max(recencyVec)` is the last day.

using the scikit-learn object [MinMaxScaler](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.MinMaxScaler.html), hence transforming the `recency` values by scaling each feature to the given range as suggested in How to [Normalize and Standardize Time Series Data in Python](https://machinelearningmastery.com/normalize-standardize-time-series-data-python/)

Is this the correct approach for this numerical formulation? Which alternative approach may be possible to normalize the timestamp values when summed to other discrete numeric values?

Answer (score 2):

Is `recency` then an absolute UNIX timestamp? Or do you already subtract the current timestamp? If not, then depending on your goal, it might be sufficient to simply subtract the current unix timestamp from `recency`, so that it consistently describes "seconds from now", or the time delta instead of absolute unix time.
Of course, that would create quite a large score, but it will be consistent.

What scaling you use depends on your goal (what is an acceptable `score`?), but many are valid as long as they're monotonic. In addition to the min-max scaling (where I would suggest using `0` as minimum and set maximum to some known maximum time offset), you might also want to consider the log transformation.

Comment: `recency` is an array of unix timestamps: `[1621250658000, 1619371761000, ...]`. For acceptable value of `score` I do not have a specific reference. It's intended to give more importance to more recent items, and be proportional to that `frequency` field (it's a counter of documents updates) by the  sums to the count of all available properties.